# User cannot select from table when having SELECT permissions if CONTROL is denied

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database, role

I'm setting up my database on an Azure SQL Server instance.

(I know the principal names are terrible, it's just a dry run test)

I created a login ("Test"), a user ("Test"), a schema ("Test"), added a table to the schema ("TestTable", created a role ("TestWriter"), set role permissions for the schema and added the user to the role.

I granted the role the following permissions:

```
GRANT 
    INSERT, 
    SELECT, 
    UPDATE
ON SCHEMA::Test
    TO TestWriter
GO
```

and denied all other permissions, following the practice of "least permissions" (i.e. giving a role/user only the minimum permissions it needs):

```
DENY 
    DELETE, 
    ALTER, 
    CONTROL, 
    EXECUTE, 
    REFERENCES, 
    TAKE OWNERSHIP, 
    VIEW DEFINITION 
ON SCHEMA::Test
    TO TestWriter
GO
```

however then there was an error selecting and/or inserting into the table in the schema, the error being

`The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'TestTable', database 'TestDb', schema 'Test'.`

through trial and error I found out the problem is fixed if I `GRANT` `CONTROL` permission to the role.

However, from what I read the `CONTROL` permission isn't something I'd want to grant willy-nilly to anyone who just needs to SELECT/INSERT into a table. Is there something I am missing? Is it possible to SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE a table WITHOUT having `CONTROL` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to explicitly `DENY` any of those permissions since SQL Server is **implicitly** *deny-first*, meaning a **Login** / **User** / **Security Principal** (such as a **Role**) has no access to anything until you've **explicitly** granted access (either via scripting it with T-SQL using the `GRANT` keyword or using the UI that **SSMS** provides). **Explicitly** denying a permission takes precedent even over an explicit `GRANT`.

Think of it this way, there are three states a permission can be in and the order of precedence (by highest precedence first) for permissions in SQL Server work like this: **Explicit** `DENY` > **Explicit** `GRANT` > **Implicit** *deny-first* (default)

By explicitly granting `CONTROL`, you're not solving the problem or understanding the root is, rather you're just sidestepping it with a workaround by granting a very wide permission set (the **explicit** `GRANT` here supercedes the **implicit** *deny-first* nature).

Outside of that, I'm unsure of what your root issue actually is, but I'd recommend by first [**revoking**](https://www.sqlstudies.com/2014/08/04/deny-vs-revoke/amp/) (not granting) all of the explicit `DENY` permissions you've mapped to the `TestWriter` role, and start testing what your `Test` **user** has access to.

Comment: I took your advice and revoked all deny permissions. Also tested it with revoking the CONTROL only and it works. Which just puzzles me even more, since NOT grating control it should be implicitly denied but it works but when explicitly denying it - it doesn't.

Comment: @user14092802 I'm not an expert on SQL Server permissions unfortunately, I just know high level how they work. My guess would be that since SQL Server follows **deny-first** security patterns, when you `DENY CONTROL` it effectively cascadingly explicitly denies all permissions under the `CONTROL` permission, which as you read, is a lot of things. And even if you explicitly `GRANT` one of those things back to a **User**, it still is explicitly denied (**Explicit Deny** > **Explicit Grant**). But when you leave everything unpermissioned and in its default state of implicitly denied and then...

Comment: ...you explicitly `GRANT` the granular permissions you want, then the system should work as you need (**Explicit Grant** > **Implicit Deny**).

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's something like that.